# AUGraph - reconfigure on the fly?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

I am trying to rearrange the nodes in an AUGraph during playback (render). In particular, I am trying to switch between these two setups:

1. Multichannel Mixer -> Remote I/O
2. Multichannel Mixer -> Converter #0 -> Bandpass Filter -> Converter #1 -> Remote I/O

*(The stream converters are needed because the bandpass filter uses a floating point format)*

**Both setups atre tested and work on their own**; i.e., if I start with a given setup (node connections), the graph renders properly.
But when I try to rearrange the nodes during playback, something goes wrong.

My connection code is this:

```
void enableBandpassFilter(Boolean enable)
{
    OSStatus result;

    if (enable) {

        // [ A ] Enable

        // Connect mixer to converter0
        result = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(processingGraph,       // (in) graph
                                         mixerNode,             // (in) src node
                                         0,                     // (in) src output number
                                         converterNode0,        // (in) dst node
                                         0);                    // (in) dst input number
        if ( result != noErr ){
            DLog(@"AUGraphConnectNodeInput() Failed for mixer->converter0");
        }

        // Connect converter0 to bandpass
        result = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(processingGraph,       // (in) graph
                                         converterNode0,        // (in) src node
                                         0,                     // (in) src output number
                                         bandpassNode,          // (in) dst node
                                         0);                    // (in) dst input number
        if ( result != noErr ){
            DLog(@"AUGraphConnectNodeInput() Failed for converter0->bandpass");
        }

        // Connect bandpass to converter1
        result = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(processingGraph,       // (in) graph
                                         bandpassNode,          // (in) src node
                                         0,                     // (in) src output number
                                         converterNode1,        // (in) dst node
                                         0);                    // (in) dst input number
        if ( result != noErr ){
            DLog(@"AUGraphConnectNodeInput() Failed for bandpass->converter1");
        }

        // Connect converter1 to i/o
        result = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(processingGraph,
                                         converterNode1,
                                         0,
                                         remoteIONode,
                                         0);
        if ( result != noErr ){
            DLog(@"AUGraphConnectNodeInput() Failed for converter1->output");
        }
    }
    else{
        // [ B ] Disable


        result = AUGraphDisconnectNodeInput(processingGraph,
                                            remoteIONode,
                                            0);
        if ( result != noErr ){
            DLog(@"AUGraphDisconnectNodeInput() Failed for output");
        }

        // Connect mixer to remote I/O
        result = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(processingGraph,       // (in) graph
                                         mixerNode,             // (in) src node
                                         0,                     // (in) src output number
                                         remoteIONode,          // (in) dst node
                                         0);                    // (in) dst input number
        if ( result != noErr ){
            DLog(@"AUGraphConnectNodeInput() Failed for mixer->output");
        }
    }
}
```

(The graph and nodes are file-scope globals. This C function is defined in the same file as my Obj-C sound manager class). I use this same function both at graph initialization *and* afterwards for switching.

I've tried two approaches:

- Calling the `enableBandpassFilter()` right away (from within an
  Obj-C method), and
- Register a notification callback with `AUGraphAddRenderNotify()`
  (which runs in the 'real time priority thread') and calling
  `enableBandpassFilter()` from within the callback.

Both approaches fail miserably. To make thing simple and avoid the pitfall of disconnected audio units not being initialized when the graph starts, I start with the 5 node configuration #2 above (bandpass filter: on) and from there try to switch to the bypass configuration #1 above (bandpass filter: off).

On startup, the audio graph looks like this:

```
AudioUnitGraph 0x1E9B000:
  Member Nodes:
    node 1: 'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl', instance 0x170820fe0 O  
    node 2: 'aufc' 'conv' 'appl', instance 0x178424040 O  
    node 3: 'aufx' 'bpas' 'appl', instance 0x1784241a0 O  
    node 4: 'aufc' 'conv' 'appl', instance 0x1708295a0 O  
    node 5: 'auou' 'rioc' 'appl', instance 0x17082b020 O  
  Connections:
    node   1 bus   0 => node   2 bus   0  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000C2C) 8.24-bit little-endian signed integer, deinterleaved]
    node   2 bus   0 => node   3 bus   0  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
    node   3 bus   0 => node   4 bus   0  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
    node   4 bus   0 => node   5 bus   0  [ 2 ch,      0 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
  Input Callbacks:
    {0x10000d17c, 0x10004ea90} => node   1 bus   0  [2 ch, 44100 Hz]
    {0x10000d17c, 0x10004ea90} => node   1 bus   1  [2 ch, 44100 Hz]
    {0x10000d17c, 0x10004ea90} => node   1 bus   2  [2 ch, 44100 Hz]
    {0x10000d17c, 0x10004ea90} => node   1 bus   3  [2 ch, 44100 Hz]
  CurrentState:
    mLastUpdateError=0, eventsToProcess=F, isInitialized=F, isRunning=F
```

(The "0Hz" part in the last connection is a bit alarming, but sound flows properly at this point)

When I try to bypass the filter using callbacks, I get the dreaded -10861 error (`kAUGraphErr_InvalidConnection`) when connection the mixer to the output.

When I try to bypass the filter on the main thread (Obj-C method), I get no error result codes but the filter is not deactivated.

In both cases, after the switch the graph log becomes this:

```
AudioUnitGraph 0x1EA2000:
  Member Nodes:
    node 1: 'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl', instance 0x178228d80 O I
    node 2: 'aufc' 'conv' 'appl', instance 0x17062c760 O I
    node 3: 'aufx' 'bpas' 'appl', instance 0x17062dfe0 O I
    node 4: 'aufc' 'conv' 'appl', instance 0x170636d00 O I
    node 5: 'auou' 'rioc' 'appl', instance 0x170637200 O I
  Connections:
    node   1 bus   0 => node   2 bus   0  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000C2C) 8.24-bit little-endian signed integer, deinterleaved]
    node   2 bus   0 => node   3 bus   0  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
    node   3 bus   0 => node   4 bus   0  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
  Input Callbacks:
    {0x1000452fc, 0x100086a40} => node   1 bus   0  [2 ch, 44100 Hz]
    {0x1000452fc, 0x100086a40} => node   1 bus   1  [2 ch, 44100 Hz]
    {0x1000452fc, 0x100086a40} => node   1 bus   2  [2 ch, 44100 Hz]
    {0x1000452fc, 0x100086a40} => node   1 bus   3  [2 ch, 44100 Hz]
  Problem Events when updated:
    connect:source=1,bus=0,dest=5,bus=0
  CurrentState:
    mLastUpdateError=0, eventsToProcess=F, isInitialized=T, isRunning=T (1)
```

*(Notice the **Problem Events when updated:** part detailing the impossibility to connect `Multichannel Mixer` and `Remote I/O`. Also, the `O` after each node changes into `O I`.)*

I can't believe the nodes are incompatible, because if I start form that configuration, it works.

So, what is the proper way to reconnect nodes on the fly? What am I missing?

*Sorry for the long question.

**EDIT (Solution?):** As I mentioned in the comments, it turns out the graph rewiring ***must be done in the main thread***, and not in the Core Audio thread (the relevant objects are locked in that context). I moved the rewiring code to the main thread (instance method), and also added a call to `AUGraphClearConnections()` *before* any call to `AUGraphConnectNodeInput()`, and now it works, **even if I don't stop/restart the graph**.

The only problem right now is, whenever I rewire, all sounds playing stop (render callbacks stop being called) until I stop/start those sounds again. I must inspect each bus of the mixer to see if the callback is attached, bus enabled, etc... I'll do just that right now.

Comment: Personal experience: I tested for a couple of days and never get any AU components to be successfully re-connected on the fly, though the document says it could.... I always have to stop the Audio Graph, disconnect and re-connect, then re-start the Audio Graph.

Comment: OK, but that works then? Does it produce any audible artifacts, or is it seamless?

Comment: Just found this blog post. It says that AUGraphUpdate should always be called from the main thread, ***not*** the Core Audio thread...    http://forum.theamazingaudioengine.com/discussion/96/incomplete-project-here-for-posterity-transactions/p1

Comment: Thanks for the blog post, I thought I called everything on main, but will check again. The Stop and Start AUGraph way is not seamless, as I was playing back the audio collected from microphone real time, I could hear a very short Off-Time.

Comment: Check my edit: you don't need to stop the graph, just use AUGraphClearConnections(). Or at least that works for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out the graph rewiring must be done in the main thread, and not in the Core Audio thread: the relevant objects are locked in that context (some of the -admittedly fragmented, sometimes contradictory?- Core Audio official documentation seemed to suggest you can do it from any context, because AUGraph is thread safe and takes care of everything).

So I moved the rewiring code to an instance method of my class (which runs on the main thread), and also added a call to `AUGraphClearConnections()` before any call to `AUGraphConnectNodeInput()`, and now it works, even if I don't stop/restart the graph.

So what I do is (Main thread):

1. Call `AUGraphClearConnections()` (disconnects everything).
2. Make all connections (new nodes and existing ones, full graph in its definitive form). This includes nodes as well as input render callbacks.
3. Call `AUGRaphUpdate()` in **synchronous** mode (pass `NULL` to second parameter).

This does the trick.

Comment: I'll wait a couple if days before accepting my own answer, just in case something better comes along.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas. The trick was AUGRaphUpdate. I finally get mine to work as well.